# Debugging mscorlib in .Net 4.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, .net-4.0, mscorlib

I'm getting the following exception from System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars() in mscorlib:

> [ArgumentException: Illegal characters
>   in path.]
>   System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String
>   path) +142
>   System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String
>   path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32
>   maxPathLength) +100
>   System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String
>   path) +187
>   System.Xml.XmlResolver.ResolveUri(Uri
>   baseUri, String relativeUri) +114
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String
>   url, XmlNameTable nt) +135
>   System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String
>   filename) +85
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.WebEditRibbon.ConvertToJson(String
>   layout) +210
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.WebEditRibbon.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   output, Item item) +1268
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   output) +387
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ICollection children) +246
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +315
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +48
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>   +11279890    System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer, ICollection children) +246
>   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer) +40
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5274

The thing is, I don't what the path value is that's causing this error. It would help if I could debug the method so I can see the value of the path parameter. I enabled stepping into the .Net Framework code in Visual Studio 2010. I've also loaded the related .Net Framework Symbols from the Microsoft Symbol Servers. However, it seems these PDBs don't include the source; so I can't step into CheckInvalidPathChars and retrieve the path value.

Is it possible to debug mscorlib and step through its source?

Relevant info:

- .Net Framework 4.0.
- Visual Studio 2010

Any constructive input is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the *reference source* for the .NET libraries.
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Looking at your stacktrace, the problem appears to be originating in `Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.WebEditRibbon.ConvertToJson`.  That thing is trying to load an XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Using reflector would allow you to do that.
Is it possible that you enabled to break on all exceptions? Doing that would certainly account for internal exceptions showing up in the debugger. If this is the case, you can safely ignore the exception.

Comment: I actually tried Reflector Pro; disassembling mscorlib and using the generated Symbols to debug. However, the debugging support was flaky and I wasn't able to access the path parameter value or any internal variable in the method for that matter.

Comment: No need to dis-assemble. The source is available. Go download it. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well mscorlib.dll on your machine is of release build so even though you can very well debug into it, you won't be able to see values local variables/objects etc. The code in this binary is optimized. If you want perfect debugging experience of Microsoft .NET code then you will need to install debug version of .NET on your machine.