# How to Debug Mscorlib.dll in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

I could do reverse engineer of other custom dlls (my own created `.net` assemblies) successfully but I couldn't do it on `mscorlib.dll` with the same steps.

I have tried to generate pdb of `mscorlib.dll` using jetbrains dotpeek.

My visual studio debugging option has been set to the folder containing that pdb.

I tried to put the `mscorlib.ini` file to set the code Optimization to No, like this:

```
[.NET Framework Debugging Control]  
GenerateTrackingInfo=1  
AllowOptimize=0
```

and put the file on the same location where the temporary dll is loaded (e.g.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089).

When I attach my VS to a process, I could see that the Optimized value is still 'Yes' in Visual Studio's Modules.

Appreciate if anyone can guide me the step by step instructions on how to debug the mscorlib.dll when attaching VS to a process using mscorlib.dll.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe mscorlib is ngen'ed. So the AllowOptimize value has no effect during "runtime". It would have to be specified during the ngen.exe run (see the first "Note" on [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/making-an-image-easier-to-debug)).

Comment: @Alexander Ng, We often debug it after we get the reference source for the .NET libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061676/debugging-mscorlib-in-net-4-0, It seems that you just load the dll file which was in release build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mscorlib.dll is [ngen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator)'d. You'll also need to set `COMPLUS_ZapDisable` environment variable to prevent CLR from loading ngen'd assemblies:

`set COMPLUS_ZapDisable=1`